# My project turned black and can only see the outline

Tags: animation

help

[image]

after i closed blender and opened again my project turned black ive tried rendering it again but that doesn't help please

Comment: hard to know with such a description. please upload the file. Check if you have not disabled the light or are in a different layer

Answer (score 0):

You have it in wireframe mode. You need to select solid, texture, or material from the bar at the bottom of the viewport above the timeline (Assuming you are using the default layout)

Comment: Doesn't matter what mode you're on when rendering, and because there's the transparency checker background in the image he uploaded you can tell it's the rendered image, not the 3D viewport. His problem is most likely to be that he doesn't have turned on the layer where the lights are.

Comment: Ohh, it's rendered :P